# Можно ли создать приложение - одновременно и оконное, и консольное?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, wxwidgets

Есть программа (Windows, на VC++, но думаю, это не принципиально), которая открывает окно, интерактивно позволяет открыть файл с данными, задать параметры расчетов, просчитать, вывести результаты. Словом, обычное расчетное приложение.

Но иногда есть целый ряд файлов с данными, для которых параметры расчетов одинаковы, и хочется просто запустить программу с ключиками в пакетном файле, пусть считает.

Вижу такие варианты.

1. Сделать вторую программу на основании первой, в принципе, несложно. Но тогда надо постоянно согласовывать исходники, а это чревато ошибками, лишней работой etc etc.
2. Сделать расчетную консольную программу, которую как-то скрытно вызывать при необходимости расчетов из оконной. Как ее корректно вызвать в фоне, чтоб она не попыталась открыть консоль?
3. Попытаться выделить расчетную часть в DLL, которую подгружать из консольной и из оконной программ. Минус - использую wxWidgets и DialogBlocks, и что-то никак не могу сообразить, как в проекте DialogBlocks делать кроме `exe` еще и `dll`, а держать два отдельных проекта тоже не хочется.

Конечно, идеально - чтоб программа по переданным ключам сама принимала решение о том, как ей запуститься - как консольной или как оконной, но что-то не представляю, как такого добиться.

Как считаете, какой подход будет лучше (проще и надежнее) всего?

Comment: Добавьте парсинг командной строки и если параметры заданы - не рисуйте GUI, например. По пункту один: добавляете в проект студии подпроект и используете в них общие сорцы. Проблемы согласования не будут.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ну, как я понимаю, линковщик уже создает приложение того или иного типа... Плюс wxWidgets вообще не имеет функции main() - т.е. разбор командной строки я должен делать уже в оконном приложении (если бы кто-то подсказал, как обойти wxWidgets и заставить его, грубо говоря, включаться по запросу, был бы признателен).

Comment: У меня отладочные сборки Qt имеют и консольное окно, так что принципиальная возможность есть. Получение командной строки - GetCommandLine из WinAPI.

Comment: да, можно создать такое приложение. В случае wxWidgets  нужно просто в методе onInit не создавать окно и его не будет. А потом, пользуясь AllocConsole, открываете себе консольку.

Comment: @KoVadim Ага, попробую, спасибо за совет.

Comment: @KoVadim Попробовал в тестовом режиме :) Минус в том, что в батнике получается мгновенный запуск сразу большого количества программ, а хотелось бы, чтоб, скажем, при запуске из Far'а вывод шел в том же консольном окне. Такое принципиально возможно? Как я понимаю, можно сделать приложение консольным, но тогда при запуске как оконного - щелчками мыши - будет кроме окон выскакивать еще и консоль?

Comment: да, возможно. Самое простое - с помощью тех же параметров командной строки.

Comment: @KoVadim А подробнее можно? Итак, вызываю AllocConsole, консоль образуется. Но что-то ни вывод в нее, ни ввод не работают (через стандартные функции). Но это отдельная консоль, не связанная с консольным окном Far. Простите, а нельзя, чтоб не загромождать тут комментариями, написать вам на e-mail?