# Имитация последовательности команд в приложении wxWidgets

Tags: c++, visual-c++, события, wxwidgets

Вдогонку к моему другому [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512362/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5). Как вариант, хотелось бы попробовать в оконном приложении wxWidgets просто программно имитировать команды меню, кнопок и т.п. - чтобы автоматизировать расчет, как будто это делает человек. Что-то типа макроса :)

Только что-то никак не могу найти, как передавать эти команды (как вариант, в хелпе нашел `GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent(event)`), и какая функция должна этим заниматься, чтоб отправка команд пошла сразу, а не по моей команде :) - не в `OnInit` же главного окна - окно-то к этому моменту должно быть полностью создано и инициализировано.

Как все это сделать корректно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, раз никто ничего не отвечает, я сам :)

Итак, как это делается - просто создаем соответствующий `event` и отправляем его на обработку.

```
wxCommandEvent event;
event.SetEventObject(this);
event.SetEventType(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED);
event.SetId(id_CalcDs);
GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent(event);
```

Тонкость в том (что я сразу не сообразил), что не обработка события вызывает нажатие кнопки, скажем, а наоборот. Т.е. если мне надо поменять, скажем, состояние переключателя TOGGLE_BUTTON, то надо не просто обработать событие, но сначала изменить его состояние - примерно

```
event.SetEventType(wxEVT_COMMAND_TOGGLEBUTTON_CLICKED);
event.SetId(id_ToggleButton);
toggleButton->SetValue(!toggleButton->GetValue());  // Меняем состояние
GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent(event);
```

Ну, и последнее - как автоматизировать инициацию вызова...
В принципе, работало в `CreateControls()` главного окна, но мне показалось это несколько "стрёмным", так что я сделал - не знаю уж, насколько правильно - инициацию этого процесса в обработчике `OnIdle()` - примерно так:

```
void MainWindow::OnIdle( wxIdleEvent& event)
{
    static bool once = true;
    if (once)
    {
        once = false;
        AutoRun();     // Здесь вся обработка последовательности
    }
}
```

Не очень уверен в абсолютной корректности, но - работает.

Жду критику :)